# Find if link targets image with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to write a script that will find all `<a>` tags whose target is either a jpg, gif, or png and attach a function to them.

```
$('a')
    .filter(function(){
        return this.href.match(/*probably some regex here?*/)
    })
    .bind('mouseover', function(){
        alert('foo');
    })
```

This should work, but I don't know what the regex would look like. If there's a better way, please let me know that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost had it!!!

```
$('a[href]').filter(function() {
  return /(jpg|gif|png)$/.test($(this).attr('href'))
}).bind('mouseover', function(){
  alert('foo');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check filename with case insensitive regex. Because some files can be ".JPEG" instead of ".jpeg". So try this:

```
var file = "life/is/short.JPG"

if (/(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/i.test(file)) {
    alert("the file is an image");
}
else {
    alert("the file is not an image");
}
```