# Check if a link is an image

Tags: javascript, regex, image, url

I need to check whether a URL is an image.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365367/find-if-link-targets-image-with-javascript-jquery)

```
/(jpg|gif|png)$/.test(...
```

raises a false positive in my (special) case when there's an extension in a non-image URL

```
http://www.example.com/jpg/bpgpage/
```

(PS: can't use jquery, only javascript/regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can add a dot `.` before the regular expression, as such:

```
  /\.(jpg|gif|png)$/.test( ..
```

That will try to match `.jpg`, `.gif` and `.png` in URLs.
The regular expression you mentioned though, does try to search for `jpg`, `gif` and `png` only at the end of the URL, so I'm not sure how it matched `http://www.example.com/jpg/bpgpage/`.

If you ommit the dot `.` though, it will still match `http://www.example.com/jpg`

Comment: The dollar sign here means that it will only find the extensions at the END of the URL, so it won't match any URL that contains the extension somewhere else inside of it.

Comment: I know, but it would still match `http://www.example.com/jpg` which is a directory.

Comment: @laggingreflex That was it?

Comment: @laggingreflex haha classic

Answer (score 6):

Provided that the uri ends with the extension, this should work every time.

**Code:**

```
var isUriImage = function(uri) {
    //make sure we remove any nasty GET params 
    uri = uri.split('?')[0];
    //moving on, split the uri into parts that had dots before them
    var parts = uri.split('.');
    //get the last part ( should be the extension )
    var extension = parts[parts.length-1];
    //define some image types to test against
    var imageTypes = ['jpg','jpeg','tiff','png','gif','bmp'];
    //check if the extension matches anything in the list.
    if(imageTypes.indexOf(extension) !== -1) {
        return true;   
    }
}
```

**Example**:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fMCFB/1/

Comment: Good one. I would remove the `?` part before splitting by dots, though, just to be sure.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos haha yeah i did that in the example, updating it in the answer code now ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can verify in the content Type header here's a function example:

```
async function verifyUrlImage(url){
try{
    let resp= $.ajax(url);
    await resp;
    let headers=resp.getAllResponseHeaders().split(/\n/g);
    for(let i=0;i<=headers.length;i++){
        let hd=headers[i].split(': ')
        if (hd[0]=='content-type' && hd[1].indexOf('image')==0)
           return true;
    }
}
catch{}
return false;
}
```

So this will look if content-type starts with image then the link is an image acording this image types:
https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image

you can test it:

```
let isImage = await verifyUrlImage('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/332cf4cffa6c5161c026485b98655079?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do, where "str" is the string you're matching:

```
return (str.match(/\.(jpg|gif|png)$/)!= null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// function for check the type of any source 
function checkExtension(file) {
    var extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
    switch (extension) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'png':
    case 'gif':
        return "img" // There's was a typo in the example where
        break; // the alert ended with pdf instead of gif.
    case 'mp4':
    case 'mp3':
    case 'ogg':
        return "video"
        break;
    case 'html':
        return "html"
        break;
 
    }
};
var ex = checkExtension("if-a-link-is-an-image.png")
console.log(ex)
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not pull the last three characters using substr?

```
url.substr(url.length-3, 3);
```